# Configure Apache to execute PHP scripts with PHP all uppercase filename extension

Tags: php, apache

I have 2 files

One is `list.php` (php in lowercase)

```
<html>
<body>
    <b> 0 or 1 </b><br><pre>
    <?php 

        if(1 > 0){
            echo "1";

        }
        else
        {
          echo "0";
        }

    ?></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the file I get 0.

But another file is `list.PHP` (PHP in uppercase) and when I run it I get the code as text!

I tried setting `AllowOverride all` in apache but still have the same problem.

Comment: if you're running this off a * NIX system, it's case-sensitive. `.php` and `.PHP` are two different animals.

Comment: so can i do anything to make it work in case of .PHP

Comment: if the file exists and was created with an uppercase extension, I shouldn't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: The question is though: *why?* You're probably going to stumble somewhere, or someone may bookmark a page and return to it changing the extension. Crazier things have happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration file httpd.conf of Apache, look for the following line:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Add another line saying:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .PHP
```

The changes require you to restart the Apache daemon.

Comment: i didn't find this line :/  but i tried in .htaccess because someone fixed this problem in that way but same problem :/

Comment: @Vendetta If you didn't restart Apache/PHP after making that change, it won't take effect until you do.

Comment: Is this your own server or is this shared hosting? In the case of shared hosting, you do not have access to the Apache configuration file and will not be able to assign file extensions with certain functionalities

Comment: @NineBerry   My own servr

Comment: Well, then look in the httpd.conf file whether you see some line that contains ".php". For example, it might say AddHandler instead of AddType

Comment: @Fred-ii- i restarted it :/

Comment: it works now ! .. i typed the line in .htaccess first i typed the line `AddType application/x-httpd-php .PHP
` in wrong way but now i changed it then it worked !