# Apache case insensitve. Interpret extension .php and not .PHP (but find it and download it)

Tags: php, regex, apache

Hello I want to perform a test and I would like to know how to configure my apache2 server (Apache/2.4.18) to be case insensitive.

When searching iNdeX.php return the page too.

I also want it to interpret all the .php files, but when search for the same file with the extension PHP in mayus, not interpret it, but search it and download the code, instead of just not finding it.

For example I browse:

localhost/index.php -> I get the page

localhost/iNDex.php -> I get the page

localhost/index.PHP -> I don't get a 404 Not Found, I download the code

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure Apache to execute PHP scripts with PHP all uppercase filename extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947589/configure-apache-to-execute-php-scripts-with-php-all-uppercase-filename-extensio)

Comment: Interesting post but this is far from what I am looking for.
That post is about a solution to interpret .PHP extension as php, what I want is different. I want to be able to access the files Case Insensitive, as I said, like:  `INdeX.php` and when requesting a file `.PHP`, find it, and recieve it, but not interpret it, just be given the code displayed.

Maybe the approach is through redirect REGEX